# Inverse result of a query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables in MySQL. Staff with fields `id`, `name`, `surname`, `telephone`, `adress`, `id_work`.

Work with fields `id`, `name`.

Absence with fields `id`, `name`, `id_staff`.

I have the following query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM staff s, work w, absence a 
WHERE s.id=a.id_staff 
AND s.id_work=w.id 
AND w.name='sales manager' 
AND a.name='disease'.
```

The aforementioned query returns the staff which have the post of sales and are ill.

Is there is a way to return the inverse result namely the staff which have the post of sales but are not ill?

I change my where clause with where not exists but did not work

Comment: what determine who is ill ? a.name = 'disease' ? why not a.name != 'disease' ?

Comment: `and a.name <> 'disease'` maybe? It's a bit unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I try this and return count 0

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

One method of solving this uses `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM staff s JOIN
     work w
     s.id_work = w.id LEFT JOIN
     absence a 
     ON s.id = a.id_staff AND a.name = 'disease'
WHERE w.name='sales manager' AND a.id_staff IS NULL;
```

Comment: If you are going to boldly state 'never use commas in the the `FROM` clause' it would be good to include why you consider it bad practice. Code is rarely a 'never' or 'always' situation, but about context and trade offs.

Answer (score 0):

You should also avoid 'CROSS JOIN' except where it is necessary :

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM staff s 
INNER JOIN work w ON s.id_work = w.id 
LEFT JOIN absence a ON s.id = a.id_staff 
WHERE w.name='sales manager' 
AND a.name = 'disease' 
AND a.id_staff IS NULL;
```